# How to use '==' in Template string in LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, template

I want to set check array value dynamically while looping in template.

My array:

```
    Products =[
            {ProductName: 'JSON1', Status: 'Active'},
            {ProductName: 'JSON2', Status: 'Active'},
            {ProductName: 'JSON3', Status: 'Current'},
            {ProductName: 'JSON4', Status: 'InActive'},
            ...
        ];
    


   <template for:each={Products} for:item="pr">
   <div if:true={pr.status =='Active'}>
   <ul class="grid">
      <li class="grid-col">
         <lightning-button  onclick={approveMethod}>New</lightning-button>
      </li>
   </ul>
   </div>
   <div if:true={pr.status =='Current'}>
   <ul class="grid">
      <li class="grid-col">
         <lightning-button  onclick={stockMethod}>In stock</lightning-button>
      </li>
   </ul>
   </div>
   <div if:true={pr.status =='InActive'}>            
   <ul class="grid">
      <li class="grid-col">
         No Button
      </li>
   </ul>
   </div>
</template>
```

Based on the status the button should be visible how would do that in LWC ?

Answer (score 4):

> How to use '==' in Template string in LWC?

You don't. You need to instead manipulate your data such that you can evaluate it as true/false directly. Something like this:

```
this.Products = this.Products.map((product) => ({
  ...product,
  isActive: product.Status === "Active",
  isInactive: product.Status === "InActive",
  isCurrent: product.Status === "Current",
}));
```

And then in your template:

```
<div if:true={pr.isActive}>
```

Comment: Indeed. Basically, computational expressions exist in the JavaScript, but not in the template. A template can access properties and functions. Of course the expression could be provided in a `get` property function rather than as an actual property.